# How can I find my salesforce.com API request limit?

Tags: rest-api, api

Can you tell what your API limit is for a 24 hour period?

It appears that salesforce has Unlimited,  Developer, Gold plans.

How can I tell which one I have? I'm looking to retrieve it though the API, or through the web interface (assuming I am not an administrator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup menu, administration, organization, company profile.  You can see your daily limit and your current number used.

Comment: Excellent, apparently I have 52,000 !

Comment: @spuder I though you needed this information through some API exposed !

Comment: I'm looking for either.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to count this through any API as salesforce don't expose this information.Its only available in sfdc admin set up.

However there is small workaround that you may try.Although be cautious that its just workaround

```
WebService static string GetAPIUsage() {
  PageReference pr = new PageReference('/00D20000000HsCQ');//use id of setup page
  pr.setRedirect(false);
  String result = pr.getContent().toString();
  Integer start_index = result.indexOf('API Requests, Last 24 Hours', 1) + 52;
  Integer end_index = result.indexOf('<', start_index);
  result = result.substring(start_index, end_index);
  result = result.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ');
return result;     
}
```