# Understanding Total API Request Limits

Tags: rest-api, administration, limits

I don't understand the total API request limits as [explained in the help section of Salesforce](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm). Since I only have access to our client's sandbox environment, I can't see what the limits are in the production environment, as suggested in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15258/how-can-i-find-my-salesforce-com-api-request-limit).

The company I'm working for is using the Unlimited Edition.

1. What does it mean to have restriction to "API Calls Per License Type". Is a license type applied at an organization level, user level? I'm not understanding this concept.
2. Why is there a minimum? Does this mean that I *must* make *x* number of API calls a day?
3. If I'm reading correctly, the Unlimited Edition should allow an unlimited number of [REST] API calls from different users? (In our case, they're logging into our application and running REST API calls under their credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are you answers:

1) Each user having Salesforce license type "Salesforce" can perform 5000 API requests. This is user level

2)  Minimum limit 0 (Zero)

3) For Unlimited Edition you can make unlimited API requests. But each user ("Salesforce license)  can make 5000 requests. In other edition like Enterprise there is limit of 1,000,000 requests. So in case of Enterprise edition if you have large number of users and one of the user has not reached to API call limit but organisation limit of 1,000,000 calls is done then that user won't be able to make request even if it has available requests.

Comment: does that means I can create 1,000,000 records in a loop via REST? Whereas, in apex it would no more than 150 DML statement in a loop? Thanks heaps!