# Understanding API Limits

Tags: api, limits

I know this question has been asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45586/understanding-total-api-request-limits), but something doesn't quite add up.

I'm reading the [API Request Limit Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm) and I have a few questions.

1. What does the minimum column mean in the Total API Request Limit? The [other SE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45586/understanding-total-api-request-limits) states 0, but there are numbers in this column - what do they mean?
2. For API calls per license type, the [other SE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45586/understanding-total-api-request-limits) states that this is the total calls allowed per user with that license type. However, on the [API Request Limit Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm), the at the bottom, there is a line that states:

   ```
   Limits are enforced against the aggregate of all API calls made by the organization in a 24 hour period; limits are not on a per-user basis.
   ```

   This seems to conflict. Can anyone clarify these two items? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Minimum is a lower cap on the number of calls you'll get, for example, if you get 1000 calls per license and have 10 licenses, that's 10k calls, but if the minimum is 15k, you're allowed 15k calls, even though based on the license calc you should only get 10k.
2. the request limit page is correct, the license type rules combine to calculate the number of api calls allowed for the org in aggregate, You are not forced to use them in the same license type buckets as they were calculated.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the minimum, but one clarification on #2 - does this mean that if I have 30 Salesforce licenses on Enterprise Edition, I get 30,000 calls maximum across my entire org - and one user could use up all 30k of those calls?

Comment: Yes, that's right.